# how to convert a numeric to a character while preserving the number of zeroes?

Tags: r, string, stringr

I have a dataframe that contains numbers with a fixed number of decimals (five)

```
data <- data_frame(number = c(1.43010, 1.43011, 1.43012 ,1.43013))
# A tibble: 4 × 1
   number
    <dbl>
1 2.43010
2 2.43011
3 2.43012
4 2.43013
```

What I need to do is extract the two last characters of each `number`. But doing:

```
mutate(data, extract = str_sub(as.character(number),-2,-1))
# A tibble: 4 × 2
   number extract
    <dbl>   <chr>
1 1.43010      01
2 1.43011      11
3 1.43012      12
4 1.43013      13
```

**fails** because the zero in `2.43010` disappears during the conversion.

What can I do here?
Thanks!

Comment: Type ?sprint and have fun!

Comment: I am a noobie in R, do you mind posting an answer here? thanks!

Comment: @G5W - I think you mean `?sprintf`

Comment: Using `sprintf(%.5f, number)` instead of `as.numeric` should get you what you need.

Comment: @Benjamin `sprintf("%.5f", data$number)` with the quotes

Comment: @thelatemail that works buddy!

Comment: @thelatemail oops...yeah, that's what I meant.